# Ubuntu 14.04 installation on Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBD

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install ubuntu version 14.04 on my Lenovo ideapad 100-15IBD but every time it gets unsuccessful. I need to install ubuntu alongside windows 8.1 pro via USB. I'm using YUMI multiboot USB creator. After choosing option "Install ubuntu", the screen gets blackened. Help me with this problem.

Comment: Don't use YUMI, use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie).

Comment: @Zacharee1 Why Rufus instead of YUMI? Just the auto-detect UEFI, or is Rufus a lot newer/better/faster?

Comment: @Xen2050 I've seen a lot of problems when YUMI, UUI or Unetbootin is used that have been fixed with Rufus.